# Asp.Net events are not working in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I can't use events of buttons in WebForms.

This is my master page

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <header id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
```

You can see that I have `runat="server"`

This is my page with button:

```
<div class="slide-text">
    <div class="contact-form bottom">
        <h2>Sign In</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="Email" runat="server" name="Mail" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="E-Mail"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="Password" runat="server" name="Password" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:hyperlink navigateurl="SignUp" runat="server" text="Registration"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:button text="Sign In" id="SignInSubmit" cssclass="btn btn-submit" runat="server" onclick="SignInSubmit_Click"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that I have all necessary things.

This is the code behind:

```
protected void SignInSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User user = new User();
    user.Auth(Email.Value, Password.Value);
    if (user.IsAuth)
    {
        Session.Add("User", user);
        Response.Redirect("Account");
    }
}
```

I used debugger, but the event is just not working.

But when I put like this

```
<form runat="server">
    <div class="slide-text">
        <div class="contact-form bottom">
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="Email" runat="server" name="Mail" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="E-Mail"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" id="Password" runat="server" name="Password" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:hyperlink navigateurl="SignUp" runat="server" text="Registration"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:button text="Sign In" id="SignInSubmit" cssclass="btn btn-submit" runat="server" onclick="SignInSubmit_Click"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It is working (of course I am deleting `form` in master page).

I can't understand why it is not working.

**NOTE**
I don't get exceptions, just event not firing.

Also, when I am not using a master page
but putting `form runat` after the body, I can't use events either.

It works only like this:

```
<form runat="server">
    <div class="slide-text">
        <div class="contact-form bottom">
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="Email" runat="server" name="Mail" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="E-Mail"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" id="Password" runat="server" name="Password" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:hyperlink navigateurl="SignUp" runat="server" text="Registration"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:button text="Sign In" id="SignInSubmit" cssclass="btn btn-submit" runat="server" onclick="SignInSubmit_Click"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a form tag inside the web form when your master page already has a form tag?

Comment: Are you sure the "child" page is rendered **inside** form when using master page? It would help to see master page placeholders and how you use them on pages

Comment: everything works,but event not wokring,page renders and i dont have child form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the webform, make sure you check the checkbox that says to use the master page which contains a form already.

On your Webform.aspx no need for another form, it is already provided by the master page.

Comment: I know about it,but my events not working,its working when i put form like grandparent or parent of my event element

Comment: should I give you a test project? would that help you

Comment: if you can , I will pray for you bro

Comment: can I send you my project for test,because I think that I don`t have mistakes in code

Comment: here is my demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8qe3z9q3l70w3m/WebApplication1.zip?dl=0

Comment: its just test project for me

Comment: also I deleted images because its too large size

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan please use my sample, I tested it it works well

Comment: I know,but I do like yours it

Comment: also delete css folder

Comment: I am using template from internet and in this template there is a little code for search for that i did not noticed, its like form runat="server">another form,its my fault,but thank you for your example its help me too